# g++ preprocessor output

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

I want to get only preprocessed version of `file.cc`. I did `g++ -E file.cc`, got:

```
# 1 "file.cc"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "file.cc"
```

What  did I do wrong?

Comment: Improve your post. What was in your source file, etc.

Comment: The source file must be empty?

Comment: We can't know what you did wrong unless you say what you did, and what you expected to happen.

Answer (score 20):

Assumed that your source file contains a simple main function:

```
$ cat file.cc
int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Then, with the command you showed, the output looks like this:

```
$ g++ -E file.cc
# 1 "file.cc"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "file.cc"

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The output which is shown in the question happens when `file.cc` is empty. Note that "empty" means that the file can still contain comments, or `#ifdef` blocks with a condition which evaluates to false - since the preprocessor filters them out, they do not appear in the output either.

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want the line markers, use the -P option:

```
-P
    Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor. This might
    be useful when running the preprocessor on something that is not C code, and will
    be sent to a program which might be confused by the linemarkers.
```